# How to attach decorators to include in urls.py?

Tags: python, django, django-views

It is valid to write:

```
url(r'^/signup$', my_decorator(my_view), name='sign up')
```

How to write the same for includes?

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)) # where to write my_decorator?
```

Is this problem solvable only with the help of `request`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a straight forward way to do this. The url pattern that uses `include` has no access to the view to decorate it.

You could try writing a modified version of include that decorates any included url patterns. This might be tricky, because the included url patterns could use `include` again.